# App rejected while background mode entry is not in plist File

Tags: ios, objective-c

my App got rejected by Apple, saying "There is entry for Background Modes in plist", but i have removed the background Modes from plist, by disabling the background Modes from Capabilties section in Project setting. But the code is still there for Region Monitoring, but that all is commented for future use.

someone please help me how to properly remove background Modes from my App, in order to publish my app, or if I'm missing anything.

Comment: You'd better ask that the Apple review team.

Answer (score 1):

Besides checking the Capabilties section in Project setting what I would do is:

1. Go to your target build settings and search for "plist". This will filter some entries.
2. Among the entries above, there should be one called "Info.plist File". This is the path to the info.plist file used by your app.
3. Find where that file is located and open it in Xcode.
4. Inspect it and make sure that background mode is not set.

Also, make sure that there are no duplicated or stale .plist file associated to your app's bundle that contain background mode specification. You can filter all plist file in your project through Xcode Project Navigator (far left section in Xcode main window, look for the search field at its bottom).

Hope this helps.

Comment: Thanks, but i already checked it, plist file doesn't has entry for background modes.

Answer (score 0):

make sure that there is no service being called or invoked in the background state of the app or any streaming being done  which would force the app to remain alive after 10 minutes in the background state, also try removing "Required Background Modes"

Comment: How can i check for the services, which is forcing app to remain alive in background.

Comment: See if you have used any Streaming protocols or VOIP services in the background